# Is it possible to un-equip power armor frames from NPCs?

Tags: fallout-4

I've made my way to Corvega Assembly Plant and have encountered a "Raider Scum" enemy in Power Armor with a Fatman. I've killed him and could loot his power armor parts, as well as everything he had equipped **with the exception of his power armor frame** which he seems to be wearing still.

I am aware that NPCs can steal power armor frames with an intact fusion core, but is there a way to get frames from (preset) NPCs?

Comment: I saw a power armor frame for sale in Diamond City at the Weapons dealer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No there isn't, it's not possible to loot the power armor frame from an NPC.

What you can do is pick pocket the fusion core from the NPC, which will force them to get out of the power armor. It is also possible to damage the fusion core while the NPC is wearing the armor, which will force them to vacate the suit as well.

Comment: As for damaging, for me there was no middle ground. Either NPC did not leave (Fusion Core still intact) or I would destroy Fusion Core and the armor frame would blow up a few seconds later.

Comment: @AndreasReiff Did you find that the suit was not usable after the core exploded? I'm pretty sure I've had plenty of raiders get out of their power armor prior to the core exploding due to me shooting it, and then grabbed the frame afterward, with all the pieces broken.

Comment: @DCShannon I think it was gone, though I have not checked again. I have like 10 already and never use them anyway (playing sneaky char). I remember the last time shooting a BoS soldier in Power Armor and there was a huge explosion and I could not even find his body or Power Armor (perhaps blown too far away or into water by explosion).

Answer (score 16):

Actually, pickpocketing the core from the person will make them remove the frame, friend or foe.

However on a dead NPC you cannot currently loot the frame (Assuming this will be patched eventually)

Comment: This is true.. NPCs will exit a suit when the fusion core is removed. I do wonder if its possible to get them to run the core out of power and also get them to exit though?

Comment: @James - I remember reading that friendly NPCs do not run down the power on a fusion core at all - I assume it's the same for enemies.

Answer (score 4):

You have to pickpocket their fusion core while they're still alive. Once you do this they will immediately get out of the frame. Kill them, then take the armor. Although every time you get in it says steal. Hopefully someone else can explain how to get rid of the "steal" issue.

Comment: In the PC version, you can access the console with the tilde key, click on the armor, and then use `setownership` to make it "yours".

Comment: @T.J.L. - Does this have to be done on the frame or the individual components of the armor? (Or Both?) (Helmet etc)

Comment: Just the frame. The contents should go with.

Answer (score 1):

I just fought slag, during the battle I was able to get him to turn around and shot at his fusion core. He hopped out of the suit while it was blowing up and after the fight the power armor suit was still standing there ready for me to pilfer. My advice is: if you can get them to turn around then shoot for the core: you'll get a nice suit and do some great damage, though the suit does say "Steal" every time I get in it which is a bit of a peeve but not that big of a deal.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is currently impossible to loot the Power Armor frame from a dead NPC, there are two ways to prompt the NPC into stepping out of his armor. One is to destroy the Fusion Core, and the other is to pickpocket the Fusion Core from the NPC. Both will persuade the NPC into exiting the armor.

You will be able to enter/exit the Power Armor afterwords, although this will technically count as 'Stealing.'

The only way to change ownership of the Power Armor is using the console: Open the console (default key '~') and click on the Power Armor frame. Enter the command 'setownership', and press enter. Obviously, this is limited to the PC version currently. *(Make sure to back up your save before using console commands, as mistakes are easy to make and can cause unexpected results.)*

Comment: Pretty sure all this information was already on the page.

Answer (score -1):

Well, if you still want that power armor from that raider scum, the only way I found is by pickpocketing his fusion core... He gonna exit from the power armor... To do that, you must kill all enemy around him first. Then you sneak up to him. I suggest you sneak to him from the building with crashed tanker on top.. Then you hide behind the doorway and wait until your status bar turn "hidden". Then he gonna start patrolling the bridge again and when he stop near your doorway, you walk quietly to him and pickpocket his fusion core. He will exit his power armor. You can then blast his head with double-barreled shotgun and take his incomplete raider power armor and the fatman.

Answer (score -1):

You can also shoot the fusion core, however you need to do this when they have more than half health because it becomes a nuke effectively lol