# Can I take a Power Armor Frame from a corpse?

Tags: fallout-4, ps4

In Fallout 4, Power Armor Frames are an essential item for any hoarder. From reading the [wiki](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Power_armor_frame) it appears you can only buy them, apart from one (as well as the one you get from the Preston Harvey mission).

But after a few hours of gameplay, I encountered a Bandit boss in Power Armor. I managed to salvage the shell, but I was unable to take the frame. Is it possible to loot Frames?

Comment: [Same answer as this other question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/242683/is-it-possible-to-un-equip-power-armor-frames-from-npcs?rq=1). In short, once dead, you are out of luck, but you can steal/destroy the fusion core to force the NPC out of the frame.